# How to get Mocha-tests for Foxx to run

Tags: tdd, automated-tests, arangodb, foxx

I'm trying (and failing) to get my foxx-tests to run, following the cookbook "Testing Foxx Apps".

The tests cannot be found ( show modal with "**Completed 0 tests in 0ms ( 0 / 0 / 0 )  No tests found**" ).
In order to identity the problem, I tried to get ANY tests running, but i just get the same result ( "No tests found" ), when running tests for "official" foxx services like "*The Session Storage*" (called "*session-local*" in the "ArangoStore" when adding new Foxx-services).

So, I'm guessing something is wrong besides my own code, but can't figure out where to look, and what to look for...

Same behavior in version 2.6.12, 2.7.2 and 2.7.3

Setting the log-level to debug yields no output related to testing at all.

Thanks

Comment: I also asked on ArangoDb Google Groups
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/arangodb/bIHpB1uWqTE/uEvjj1jfBAAJ

Comment: Any example of a foxx-service with running tests would be a great start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to add mocha tests to your Foxx service is to use the `tests` field in your manifest and set it either to a single path string or an array of path strings to match the test files, e.g.:

```
"tests": "test/**"
```

or

```
"tests": ["test/one.js", "test/two.js"]
```

The [`sessions-local` service](https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/util-sessions-local) provides an example of this.

As even the official services' tests aren't working for you, I suspect an underlying problem within Foxx. It's probably better to diagnose this on the mailing list.

Comment: Ok, I'll get right on it and use the mailing list to follow up.